# dask: using compute() raised error 'apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how''?

Tags: dask

dask 2.15.0 ,
pandas 1.0.3

```
unknown_dict = dict(map(lambda columnName:(columnName,'unknown'),columns_to_clean))
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.fillna(unknown_dict)
#no problem before compute
with ProgressBar():
       print(my_dataframe.isnull().sum().compute()
my_dataframe.persist()
```

raised the following error message:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 with ProgressBar():
>   ----> 2     print(my_dataframe.isnull().sum().compute())
>         3 my_dataframe.persist()
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
>       164         dask.base.compute
>       165         """
>   --> 166         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
>       167         return result
>       168
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args,
>   **kwargs)
>       435     keys = [x.**dask_keys**() for x in collections]
>       436     postcomputes = [x.**dask_postcompute**() for x in collections]
>   --> 437     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
>       438     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
>       439
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py in get(dsk, result,
>   cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
>        82         get_id=_thread_get_id,
>        83         pack_exception=pack_exception,
>   ---> 84         **kwargs
>        85     )
>        86
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in get_async(apply_async,
>   num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally,
>   pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
>       484                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
>       485                     else:
>   --> 486                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
>       487                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
>       488                 state["cache"][key] = res
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in reraise(exc, tb)
>       314     if exc.**traceback** is not tb:
>       315         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
>   --> 316     raise exc
>       317 
>       318
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in execute_task(key,
>   task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
>       220     try:
>       221         task, data = loads(task_info)
>   --> 222         result = _execute_task(task, data)
>       223         id = get_id()
>       224         result = dumps((result, id))
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in (.0)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       113     """
>       114     if isinstance(arg, list):
>   --> 115         return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
>       116     elif istask(arg):
>       117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in (.0)
>       113     """
>       114     if isinstance(arg, list):
>   --> 115         return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
>       116     elif istask(arg):
>       117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\optimization.py in **call**(self,
>   *args)
>       989         if not len(args) == len(self.inkeys):
>       990             raise ValueError("Expected %d args, got %d" % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
>   --> 991         return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
>       992 
>       993     def **reduce**(self):
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in get(dsk, out, cache)
>       149     for key in toposort(dsk):
>       150         task = dsk[key]
>   --> 151         result = _execute_task(task, cache)
>       152         cache[key] = result
>       153     result = _execute_task(out, cache)
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in (.0)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in (.0)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       113     """
>       114     if isinstance(arg, list):
>   --> 115         return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
>       116     elif istask(arg):
>       117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in (.0)
>       113     """
>       114     if isinstance(arg, list):
>   --> 115         return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
>       116     elif istask(arg):
>       117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg,
>   cache, dsk)
>       119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
>       120         # operations in-place.
>   --> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
>       122     elif not ishashable(arg):
>       123         return arg
>
> C:\Users\KHS\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py in apply(func, args,
>   kwargs)
>        28 def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
>        29     if kwargs:
>   ---> 30         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        31     else:
>        32         return func(*args)
>
> TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'

Comment: Would it be possible to build a minimal reproducible example: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports ?  This would help diagnosis the problem. Maybe try persisting before the isnull.sum call ?  Perhaps there are issue with the construction of the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you 'quasiben', I've tried minimal code to reproduce the error, which was not possible.

However, reducing the dataset to 1 fourth its original size worked on my laptop. So I guess it has to do with knowing the threshold and limits of my system. Thank you.